# Get all unique data attribute values by value string separated by comma to list

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have this dynamic HTML

```
<select id='posto'>
  <select>
    <ul id="nazioni">
      <li data-dal="Europa, Mediterraneo">Italia</li>
      <li data-dal="Europa, Mediterraneo">Spania</li>
      <li data-dal="Asia">Cina</li>
      <li data-dal="Europa, Asia, Mediterraneo">Turchia</li>
      <li data-dal="Africa, Mediterraneo">Egitto</li>
      <li data-dal="Europa">Francia</li>
      <li data-dal="Europa">Svezia</li>
    </ul>
```

and I'm trying to fill in the select with  tags with the 'data-dal' values which I'm trying to split into separate values by the comma and space.
I'm a fresh jQuery and Javascript novice, but I've managed to piece together some sort of code from what I found here on stackOverflow and in the jQuery manual but wasn't able to piece together all the pieces into my desired code.

```
var items = {};
$('#nazioni li').each(function () {
  items[$(this).data('dal').split(', ')] = true;
});

var result = new Array();
for (var i in items) {
  result.push('<option>' + i + '</option>');
}

$('#posto').show().empty().append(result.join());

$('#posto').change(function () {
  var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  $('li[data-dal=' + selected + ']').show();
  $('li[data-dal!=' + selected + ']').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/urnPG/
I jsfiddled it. I'm unable to split the data-dal values into separate values. I'd appreciate any help or pointers in better ways to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if I have understood your question right. But let me help you with what I can. First of all heres the [JSFIDDLE Updated.](http://jsfiddle.net/urnPG/2/)

I  could split the `<li>` elements values into a unique values array and populate the `<Select>` with these values.

```
$('#nazioni li').each(function () {
   var arr = $(this).data('dal').split(", ");
   items = items.concat(arr);
 });
 var sorted = unique(items);
```

This function gets the unique values of the list.

```
function unique(list) {
   var result = [];
   $.each(list, function(i, e) {
     if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
       });
   return result;
}
```

I then tried to show up all the `<li>` elements corresponding to the drop down value that is selected.

Comment: Seriously, THANK YOU so much. This is the exact desired end result. I'll review the code and learn as much as I can it from it for good measure but after spending 20 hours today on this without getting anywhere I'll definitely catch a break first. Thank you for the help!